# What is the value of 0 XNOR 1 XNOR 1?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

We know that for 3 variables $(A=0,B=1,C=1)$, $f_1 = (A \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} B \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} C) = 1$, since the input has even number of $1$'s.

But if we were to do this step by step, $f_2 = (A \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} (B \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} C)) = (A \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} (1 \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} 1))$

Now, $1 \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} 1 = 1$. So, $f_2 = (A \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} 1) = 0 \mathop{\text{ XNOR }} 1 = 0$.

Why is $f_1 \neq f_2$ ?

Comment: why would you evaluate the right term first? Do you also $1 / 2 /  3 = 1 / (2 /3)$?!

Comment: @addy2012 So are you basically saying that XNOR is not distributive?

Comment: that's associativity. well anyway. (0 XNOR 1) XNOR 1 is not 1 as you wrote:  (0 XNOR 1) XNOR 1 = 0 XNOR 1 = 0. XNOR *is* associative.

Comment: @addy2012 Then is (a XNOR b XNOR c) different from (a XNOR (b XNOR c)) ?

Comment: no. it gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such rule as you mention, that an expression with an even number of $1$ containing only XNOR will evaluate to $1$. Your evaluation in the second part is correct. Thus there is not contradiction, just a faulty assumption/theorem from your part.